# Can my college proxy access my Tor history?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, anonymity

To access internet in college, we need to authenticate the IP and MAC address of our machine at a certain college portal. Earlier we used to have to provide proxy authentication every time the browser opened, but they changed it to this recently. However, technically I am still accessing the web using my college proxy(right?). Does the proxy track and log my Tor browser bundle history?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.
Unnless they have direct access to your machine(malware / trojans) they cannot see your history.

Comment: I'm a little confused. To reach the TOR relays, the data request first goes through my college proxy right? Thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: Yes but its all encrypted. So they only see a encrypted stream but not the data in it. They can know you use tor but not what you access with it.

Answer (score 2):

They cannot see your history in the sense that they cannot see what you are doing on Tor. However, unless you're using a [bridge](https://bridges.torproject.org/)[1], they can tell when you're connected to the Tor network. Below is the most memorable example of someone misunderstanding that concept:

http://www.theverge.com/2013/12/18/5224130/fbi-agents-tracked-harvard-bomb-threats-across-tor

[1] And even if you were using a bridge, they could find out if they were trying hard enough.

Answer (score 2):

Unless they are running endpoint (client) tracking software, it's unlikely they will be able to see your Tor browsing history.

However, they can see the dates/times when you're using Tor, as well the dates/times that their own web services were accessed via Tor. They might be able to do some traffic correlation.

Answer (score 1):

If in some period of time Firefox (on which is based TBB) or any other browser you are using is vulnerable to 0-day exploit that allows on remote attacker to access parts of the browser memory or files - yes, only in this case, someone can read your history / bookmarks / settings, etc.
But serious vulnerabilities like this are rare in browsers, so just be sure that your software is up-to-date.